# Why isn't my else in flask python not working?

Tags: python, html, flask

When I press the start button it directs me to error.html even if I choose my skin type

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

SKIN = ["Oily" , "Dry" ,"Sensitive", "Combination", "Normal"]

@app.route("/")
def index():
   return render_template("index.html", skins=SKIN)

@app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
def register():
   skin = request.form.get("skin")
   if not skin:
      return render_template("error.html")
   else:
      return render_template("info.html")
```

Comment: I would suggest to display what request you are doing so we can verify if all parameters are correct. You can use the "inspect/network" part of your browser for this

Comment: How confident are you that `"skin"` is being transmitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that your input is `name="skin type"`, whereas you are checking for an input named `skin`.

If you change the input to `name="skin"` it should work.

I also suggest in the future that you do not use spaces in any input field names.

Comment: it worked thank you !